# Why am i getting 403 error when i submit a processing request?

Tags: python, cgi

I start python local server on ubuntu, server.py:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

it's start and open index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Обработка данных форм</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/cgi-bin/form.py">
        <input type="text" name="TEXT_1">
        <input type="text" name="TEXT_2">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then i send GET request i have 403 Code Error:

```
Error response
Error code: 403
Message: CGI script is not executable ('/cgi-bin/form.py').
Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.FORBIDDEN - Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.
```

form.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
text1 = form.getfirst("TEXT_1", "не задано")
text2 = form.getfirst("TEXT_2", "не задано")

print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print("""<!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Обработка данных форм</title>
        </head>
        <body>""")

print("<h1>Обработка данных форм!</h1>")
print("<p>TEXT_1: {}</p>".format(text1))
print("<p>TEXT_2: {}</p>".format(text2))

print("""</body>
        </html>""")
```

I try on Win 10 and it works well.

I know about start server on Linyx like this:

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi
```

but i need start from file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's easy then i think:

```
chmod +x form.py
```

Now it's work.